# Add content after element scope using css only

Tags: html, css

I've following html & css structure,

```
<style>
.widget-tag a:after{content: '/'}
</style>
<div class="widget-tag">
  <a href="abc.com">abc</a>
  <a href="xyz.xom">xyz</a>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="widget-tag">
  <a href="abc.com">abc ::after</a>
  <a href="xyz.xom">xyz ::after</a>
</div>
```

I want output to be as follows, because then '|' this will be out of `a` scope.

```
<div class="widget-tag">
  <a href="abc.com">abc</a>::after
  <a href="xyz.xom">xyz</a>::after
</div>
```

As I'm working with 3rd party widget, I've following limitation,
I can only modify css - but not HTML.

So, can the output be achieved by using **css only**?

Edit: Changed the content with `/`, users in stackoverflow is getting confused with `border-right` property. Also, I'm not looking for `js` solution, as I know about it.

Comment: You may use border-right in .widget-tag a{}

Comment: why don't you use `border-right` property?

Comment: This is not possible in CSS alone. CSS does not work in this way.

Comment: @SyamPillai How can I use border-right for adding something? BTW.. That is a delimiter. It needn't `|` always.

Answer (score 0):

Use `::after` on a span enclosing the `<a>`:

```css
.widget-tag span::after { content: '/'; }
```

```html
<div class="widget-tag">
  <span><a href="abc.com">abc</a></span>
  <span><a href="xyz.xom">xyz</a></span>
</div>
```

There is no way to do this without changing the HTML.

Comment: Ok.. If there is no way, then can I ask `css` community to add it as feature?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you plan to ask them to add as a feature. It would seem that what you want is the ability to manipulate (in this case insert into) the DOM, but that by definition is not the job of CSS. It's highly unlikely that you would get a hearing. They don't care that there is some reason you can't change the HTML. If you can't work with that particular widget, then find a different one, or write your own.